# How to put Button in endAdornment in Material UI Input (like one can do it in TextField)

Tags: material-ui

It is possible to put button in endAdornment in TextField, e.g. with code:

```
<TextField size="small" type="text" id="m_general_reference" value={this.props.invoice.general_reference}
  InputProps={{
      endAdornment: (
        <InputAdornment>
          <Button variant="outlined" size="small" style={{textTransform: 'none', height: '20px'}}>
            Check General Reference
          </Button>
        </InputAdornment>
      )
    }} />
```

But this code does not work when TextField is changed to Input. Is there more or less standard markup to put endAdornment button in InputField? I am interested in more or less standard solution only and no hacks (in case of hacks I will go with TextField).

Comment: The `Input` component has a separate prop - `endAdornment` to handle this. Check [this example](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#input-adornments) for the code.